# How to change a device's screen orientation from service in android?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to change the device's orientation from portrait to landscape from a running service? I have searched but I couldn't find anything negative or positive

Comment: What do you mean? Physically rotating the device by the means of a software service is known to be quite a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

A service is a background operation while the orientation of the screen is a UI operation. You could force a service to launch an activity (but that's not recommended at all) and setting it in your manifest as in landscape orientation.